# Unable to save the text saved in the table cell using Javascript and Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with cells in it .
The cells can be edited manually by the user on clicking them and values entered are saved in the database.
When I try to do the same using 'sendKeys' method , I am unable to enter text in them.
I tried using the 'executeScript' method and changed the 'innerHTML' content of the cell , now I see that the expected text is being written in the cell.
But this is not actually being saved in the database.

```
WebElement w ;
fw.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML='55'",
                w)
```

Can someone help me figure out what the problem is in this approach.

Comment: Can you provide the html please?

Answer (score -1):

I can't add a comment yet so I will post an "answer" as a question:

Is this a site you are developing yourself? What is causing the data to be written to the table e.g. on tab out, on click on another element, key press etc?

If the "save" is happening as a result of a "key press" you can use something like:

```
selenium.keyPress("id=textbox", "\\119"); // in this case you're pressing "w"
```

More ASCII keys here:

http://www.asciitable.com/